# How do I open a vpn in R to eventually connect to a SQL database

Tags: r, command

```
cmd <- unname(Sys.which("rasdial"))
cmd_args <- c('"VPN Name"', "user","password")
system2(command = cmd, args = cmd_args)
```

When I run the above it gives me the error:

sh: 1: : Permission denied

Warning message:

In system2(command = cmd, args = cmd_args) : error in running command

I am trying to do this with openvpn. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've removed the [tag:sql] tag as this problem has nothing to do with the SQL language. Are there any spaces or special characters in `"user"` and `"password"`? `system2` (and `system`) are notoriously bad at dealing with either of those. However ... `sh: 1: : Permission denied` suggests to me that something else is wrong...

Comment: The SQL tag is what I am trying to apply a VPN to my script for as the database I am connecting to has whitelisted my VPN. There are no spaces but there are some special characters.

Comment: I understand you want to apply SQL, but I know of no SQL drivers or ODBC drivers that allow you to do things outside of what your OS networking supports. If you cannot reach the remote end, you can't even discuss SQL connection protocols or SQL code.

Comment: I see thank you, did you have a suggestion on what I could use or if what I am trying to achieve is possible through the means I have posted ?